# How to enable permission for adb.log

Tags: android, adb

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
  adb F 02-08 20:48:54  2188  1112 main.cpp:49] cannot open C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\adb.log: Permission denied

Comment: Did you enable usb debugging on the device?

Comment: yes, It was fine for android studio 2.3  . Then i updated to the latest version since then i am not not able to connect my device due to this error.

Comment: Ok try to connect your device, then press "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" in developer options, after that your device will ask you for acces to device via usb, you must accept it, and then i think everything will work fine

Comment: It did not ask for any access